# form>table (ajax)>form

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I want to do different action for each submit button. For example compare will go to "compare.php" and delete will go to "test.php". I know i can't do form inside form but i can't separate to two forms because this is one table. I thought maybe to do

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["com"])){ javascript - link to compare.php}?>
```

but how can i send the _POST to this page?
I also thought on send the ind as _GET but the user can select more then one (two deletes or two compares)
of course if you have other solutions..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
build ajax tbody...
for (i = 1; i <= numOfRows; i++)
{
oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' value='"+ ind +   "'name='com[]'>";
oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' value='"+ ind +   "'name='del[]' ;>";
.....
</script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="test.php">
        <table>
            <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th><input type="submit" value="Compare" /></th>
                 <th><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tdbody>
         </table>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have:

```
<input type="submit" value="Compare" onclick="this.form.action = 'someotherpage.php';" />
```

This will change the form action upon clicking the submit button.

Comment: Nice, although you may want to use `<form onsubmit="` instead of `<input onclick="`. Not every form submit is guaranteed to go through the submit *button* - e.g. pressing `Enter` in an edit field is not guaranteed to simulate click on the first submit button (although some browsers do that).

Comment: @Piskvor good point about `Enter` key but the original request is different action according to what button was **clicked** (at least that's what I understand) so guess pressing `Enter` is not a valid option.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Well, the option exists, it just invokes unspecified behavior (either the form will submit with the first `submit` button, or without a `submit` button at all, depending on browser and version). "Hey, user, don't do that" is not a very robust design principle ;)

Comment: @Piskvor well, setting default action is very simple only the OP can tell us more though. :)